Power Shell Error 65536. How to solve? Cannot open up PowerShell as well without this error
I am trying to open up a terminal in Visual Studio 2022, upon doing this I get the error: the terminal process has exited with code 65536. I am not able to open up my PowerShell system as well. This error has occurred randomly, I have not done anything to spark any such changes.
I have tried running sfc /scannow... I expected this to solve the issue. After this I also ran dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth. I thought that this would troubleshoot the issue. I also tried looking at google but didn't find anything useful for this specific problem.

Did you check your PowerShell profile?

@iRon is their something specific that I should check here?

Yes, if you find a .ps1 file in any of the metioned paths, rename the extention and if the resolves the issue, check the content of the specific .ps1 file.

Which .NET Framework versions are installed? Install at least .Net 4.5…

@iRon I don't believe I ever created a powershell profile. I don't think this is the issue. This powershell profile is something that I would have to had create right?

@JosefZ I have .Net 4.8 installed. I don't think this is the issue.

Anything (as other scripts) that runs under your account, could have created a profile for you without notifying you. Rather assuming, I would do some (simple) fact checking: Start --> Run --> PowerShell.exe or pwsh.exe -NoProfile. Not sure with PowerShell version it conserns here (windows 5.1 or -core- 7) but if this opens a PowerShell prompt, it is apparently the profile causing this.

You can try unintall your power shell by Open Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features. and reinstall it by using this website :
https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html
